# How to group results with different non unique columns pushing all the grouped json rows into a single array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have to tables with a one to many relation, here the query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.deployment_id, (select row_to_json(_) from (select t2.room_id, t2.unit) as _) AS rooms FROM devices_device AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN devices_deviceunitroom AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.device_id;
```

the result of this query is the following:
[image]

Now what I would like to achieve is:

- if t2.roomid and t2.unit are null I want a simple {}
- the result should be grouped so that at the end I'll have only one row representing id and deployment_id and the rooms should be all into one array

let's say something similar

```
d9:7f:d1:ed:ea:72:4a |                                      | []
a9:e7:68:95:88:0b:40 | 6c742391-436c-4fa2-8dc2-6064aad290d0 | [{"room_id":"4f1680ad-43cc-4f16-969e-1a9a00763efd","unit":0},  {"room_id":"16b26a1a-c0dd-4b88-91db-f4809c70396a","unit":1}, {"room_id":"4f1680ad-43cc-4f16-969e-1a9a00763efd","unit":2}]
```

I'm unsuccessful with GROUP BY since Postgres wants all the columns to be in the GROUP BY clause which leads to duplicates. Can somebody lead me on the good path for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able at the end to find a nice way to do it, leaving the answer here if anybody will ever have a similar problem:

The SQL I generated to achieve this is:

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.deployment_id,
  array_to_json(COALESCE(array_agg(json_build_object('room_id', t2.room_id, 'unit', t2.unit)) FILTER (WHERE t2.room_id IS NOT NULL),ARRAY[]::json[])) AS rooms

FROM
  table_1 AS t1

LEFT OUTER JOIN
  table_2 AS t2

ON
  t1.id = t2.device_id

WHERE
  t1.deployment_id = %s::uuid

GROUP BY
  t1.id;
```